# Class activation maps

Tags: conv-neural-network

I'm following this [tutorial](https://jacobgil.github.io/deeplearning/class-activation-maps) in order to get class activation maps, so I can know on what basis does CNN classify.

My model:

```
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top = False, input_shape=(imgShape[0], imgShape[1], imgShape[2]))

# CNN VGG16
model = models.Sequential()
for layer in conv_base.layers:
  model.add(layer)   
model.add(Flatten())
# classificateur modele 2 Seringue
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(nbrClass, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-6), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And after doing the fit i use this function:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input as vgg_preprocess_input
def visualize_class_activation_map(model, img_path, output_path):

    original_img = cv2.imread(img_path, 1)
    width, height, _ = original_img.shape
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    img  = image.img_to_array(img)
    img  = np.expand_dims(img , axis=0)
    img  = vgg_preprocess_input(img)


    #Get the 512 input weights to the softmax.
    class_weights = model1.get_layer('vgg16').get_layer(index=17).get_weights()[0]


    final_conv_layer = model.get_layer(index=17)

    g=model.get_layer('vgg16').get_layer(index=0)

    get_output = K.function([g.input], [final_conv_layer.output, model.layers[-1].output])
    [conv_outputs, predictions] = get_output(img)
    conv_outputs = conv_outputs[0, :, :, :]

    #Create the class activation map.
    cam = np.zeros(dtype = np.float32, shape = conv_outputs.shape[1:3])
    for i, w in enumerate(class_weights[:, 1]):
            cam += w * conv_outputs[i, :, :]
    print ("predictions", predictions)
    cam /= np.max(cam)
    cam = cv2.resize(cam, (height, width))
    heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(255*cam), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
    heatmap[np.where(cam < 0.2)] = 0
    img = heatmap*0.5 + original_img
    cv2.imwrite(output_path, img)                
    model1.summary()
    img_path=r'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\1.jpg' 
    output_path=  r'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\2.jpg' 
visualize_class_activation_map(model, img_path, output_path)
```

But I got this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor  'vgg16_input_4' with dtype float
>       and shape [?,224,224,3]
>        [[{{node vgg16_input_4}}]]

Any solution?

Comment: What's the `original_img.shape`?

Comment: the shape of images (800,250,3)